# How can I turn my JavaScript code into a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I currently only understand the very basics of bookmarklets. For example, I know that to create a bookmarklet that simply creates an alert, you would use the code

```
<a href="javascript:(function() { alert(); })()">Drag Me To Bookmarks</a>
```

However, what if you have more complex javascript, with multiple helper methods? For example, as I wanted to create some javascript code to give the alert "Good Morning" or "Good evening" depending on the time of day. Suppose also that I do this using 2 functions, as shown below

```
function getMessage() {
   if(morning) {
      return "Good Morning";
   } else if(evening) {
      return "Good Evening";
   }
}

function myAlert() {
   alert(getMessage());
}
```

How would this be turned into a bookmarklet now that the JS has multiple functions?

Comment: Use single wrapping auto-starting function and keep rest of code inside it. One example may be Visual Events: http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event+2

Comment: You can also write your code "normally", then use Ben Alman's jQuery Bookmarklet generator to generate it. It also loads jQuery (code which can be removed) if you need it: http://benalman.com/projects/run-jquery-code-bookmarklet/

Answer (score 3):

You would just wrap it in an immediately executing function like the example:

```
javascript:(function() {

   function getMessage() {
       if(morning) {
          return "Good Morning";
       } else if(evening) {
          return "Good Evening";
       }
   }

    function myAlert() {
       alert(getMessage());
    }

    myAlert();

})()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way to have the function() inner saved in a seperate file if it is too large?

Comment: Not if your plan is the bookmark the script, AFAIK.